# DNS bind9 : can't see positive/resolved answers in cache

Tags: dns, bind, bind9

Using dig, I am querying some good and bad domain records in order to test my dns.
After doing some queries, I am trying to see if they were cached and in order to do that I execute:

```
$ rndc dumpdb -cache
```

After execute it, I can see some records in the /var/cache/bind/named_dump.db, but just the bad answers, not the good ones.

I'm missing something?

Comment: Try **rndc dumpdb -all** to dump the query cache.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley. But reading the documentation in order to view all cached domain name resolutions the command to be used is rndc dumpdb -cache. The one you are sharing brings also the zones, etc.